# How to copy files with Unicode characters in file names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, filesystems

I can not copy files that have Unicode characters in their names from Ruby 1.9.2p290, on Windows 7.

For example, I have two files in a dir:

```
file
ハリー・ポッターと秘密の部屋
```

(The second name contains Japanese characters if you can not see it)

Here is the code:

```
> entries = Dir.entries(path) - %w{ . .. }
> entries[0]
=> "file"
> entries[1]
=> "???????????????" # <--- what?

> File.file? entries[0]
=> true
> File.file? entries[1]
=> false   # <---  !!! Ruby can not see it and will not copy

> entries[1].encoding.name
=> "Windows-1251"
> Encoding.find('filesystem').name
=> "Windows-1251"
```

As you see my Ruby file system encoding is "windows-1251" which is 8 bit and can not handle Japanese. Setting `default_external` and `default_internal` encodings to 'utf-8' does not help.

How can I copy those files from Ruby?

**Update**

I found a solution. It works if I use `Dir.glob` or `Dir[]` instead of Dir.entries. File names are now returned in utf-8 encoding and can be copied.

**Update #2**

My `Dir.glob` solution appears to be quite limited. It only works with "*" parameter:

```
Dir.glob("*") # <--- Shows Unicode names correctly
Dir.glob("c:/test/*") # <--- Does not work for Unicode names
```

Comment: Hmm, Windows 7, don't have possibility to reproduce your issue. Take a look at this post, maybe it may be helpful somehow: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1593850

Comment: Did you try adding `#encoding: utf-8` to the top of your code file, or running irb as `irb -Ku`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much a real solution, but as a workaround, given:

```
Dir.glob("*") # <--- Shows Unicode names correctly
Dir.glob("c:/test/*") # <--- Does not work for Unicode names
```

is there any reason you can't do this:

```
Dir.chdir("c:/test/")
Dir.glob("*")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I was looking into the same problem and it was all but obvious how to do it.

Turns out that you may specify an encoding when you call `Dir#entries` in Ruby >= 2.1.

```
Dir.entries(path, encoding: Encoding::UTF_8)
```